# How to process dictionary file for spell checking?

Tags: java, parsing, dictionary, hash

Right now, I have a dictionary.txt file in my java project. Do I need to store all these words into a hash table or something? How would I check a sample text for correct spelling by using the dictionary.txt content as a reference?

Comment: Yes, using a `HashMap` will be the most time efficient, you could call `contains()` method on the map for checking if a word exists in the dictionary, then it will be the correct spelling. If there are no memory constraints and dictionary file is of reasonable size, pre-parsing and caching the dictionary is a good approach

Comment: Ok. Can you please help me with the implementation of the HashMap? So far I did File f = new File("dictionary.txt"); and Scanner s = new Scanner(f);

Comment: Just seeing your message, hopefully answer from @Big_Foot1989 has got you started. Leave a comment if you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would recommend a `HashSet`. As you said in a comment above, you already implemented:

```
File f = new File("dictionary.txt");
Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
```

With the help of the scanner, you cann now iterate over the words of your dictionary and store it in your `HashSet`. I don't know what's the delimiter of your words at the dictionary is, by default the delimiter of the Scanner is the whitespace. If it's so for you, you can read it in like this:

```
Set<String> dict = new HashSet<String>();
File f = new File("dictionary.txt");
Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    Scanner s2 = new Scanner(s.nextLine());
    while (s2.hasNext()) {
        String s = s2.next();
        dict.add(s);
    }
}
```

The first scanner is reading the lines of your file while the second one reads in the words (just for the case that there are line breaks in your document). If your delimiter is different to the whitespace you can change it by using the `useDelimiter(String pattern)` function. If you want to check if something is spelled correctly, you can use the `contains()` method of the `Set`. Be aware that this answer asssumes that your dictionary just contains words of one language and is not meant for translation (not containing multiple languages).